# Can not install XQDT in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: XQuery Development Tools Feature 0.8.0.201107251305 (org.eclipse.wst.xquery.feature.feature.group 0.8.0.201107251305)
  Missing requirement: XQDT Core Plug-in 0.8.0.201107251305 (org.eclipse.wst.xquery.core 0.8.0.201107251305) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.dltk.core [3.0.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: XQuery Development Tools Feature 0.8.0.201107251305 (org.eclipse.wst.xquery.feature.feature.group 0.8.0.201107251305)
To: org.eclipse.wst.xquery.core [0.8.0.201107251305]
```

Answer (score 9):

The latest version of XQDT requires the dynamic languages toolkit [3.0.0, 4.0.0). In other words, the DLTK version must be >= 3.0.0 and < 4.0.0. If you're using Eclipse Juno, you'll need to download the DLTK from the Indigo update site (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo), not the Juno update site. The XQDT plug-in doesn't like the fact that the version number of the DLTK from the Juno update site is > 4.0.0.

Comment: Extremely useful.  Just to note, you only need to install the 'General Purpose Tools'/'Dynamic Languages Toolkit - Core Frameworks' item.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are missing the plugin `org.eclipse.dltk.core`.  You should install the DLTK from the Indigo update site first, and then try to install XQDT.

Alternatively, make sure that "Contact all update sites..." is checked in the install manager.

Answer (score 2):

You need the DLST packages as Andrew said. Unfortunately, you need version 3.0 or above, which the DLST project hasn't bothered to put on the Eclipse update site, despite it being classed as 'stable' on their homepage.

Annoying.

But it should be possible to install the packages manually. I haven't managed it yet myself, but I need to.